# white-space: nowrap seems to affect inner elements position: absolute

Tags: html, css

I want to have a horizontal list of items, contained in a horizontally scrollable outer-wrapper with a fixed width. The outer-wrapper has a relative position. One of the items contains an absolute positioned div.

When scrolling the outer-wrapper, I was expecting the green overlay to remain at the same position. I thought position: absolute is always relative to the first ancestor with a defined position (which would be the outer-wrapper)?

I am using white-space: nowrap for the #wrapper to get the items in a row.

```css
#outer-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#wrapper {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}

#one {
  background-color: red;
}

#two {
  background-color: blue;
}

.box {
  white-space: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}

.overlay {
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-wrapper">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="one" class="box">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="two" class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like the markup to remain as it is in the example, although this is not totally fixed.

And I can't really define a fixed width for the horizontal list.

Comment: It is staying in the same position isn't it.?..`left:0`

Comment: @Paulie_D It is scrolling with the #wrapper. At least on my chrome & firefox. Is that not the case for you?

Comment: It's working as expected. Absoluted positioned elements will scroll, you are searching for fixed positioning elements, but fixed is attached to viewport, not the closest positioned parent element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've got your question correctly then it is not possible with only HTML and CSS. However you can achieve it with jQuery as follows:

```js
$(function() {
  var wrapper = $('#outer-wrapper');
  
  $('#outer-wrapper').scroll(function() {
    $('.overlay').css({
      'marginLeft': wrapper.scrollLeft()
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#outer-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#wrapper {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}

#one {
  background-color: red;
}

#two {
  background-color: blue;
}

.box {
  white-space: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}

.overlay {
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outer-wrapper">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="one" class="box">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="two" class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can confirm that you got the question correctly ;-) Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @MatthiasKrieft You are welcome, Please up vote and accept any answer (not necessarily mine) if it solved your problem so that others can benefit from it also :)

Comment: I accepted your answer, although it did not solve my problem. Because my problem is not solvable with pure css. I'll implement the logic for the margin in the reactjs-part of the application

Comment: @MatthiasKrieft Ok, Some problems can't be fixed with pure css, we need to take help from JavaScript and its libraries at some stage in web developement)